# Is it better to generate csv in the view or in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, download

I want to create a rails application that download all the employees with their companies.

Model: company(has_many employees)

I have the following choices.

1. define #to_csv that export employee to csv with the format in Employee Model, loop employees, and call from template.
2. loop the employees, and generate the csv with the format in the template.

From the viewpoint of code design, which is better?

====added===
I'm doing it like this.

Controller:

```
def hoge
  employees = Employee.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv do
      send_data render_to_string('hoge'), filename: "hoge.csv", type: 'text/csv;chartset=utf-8'
    end
  end
end
```

Template: views/employees/hoge.csv.ruby

```
require 'csv'
CSV.generate do |csv|
  # ...
  # generate csv
end
```

Comment: model ofcourse..

Comment: @Md. Farhan Memon Since that csv file is a kind of view(browsers do not show it directly), I think it's better to generate the csv detail in the template

Comment: you want to generate a csv file right? then it should  be model and just `send` that file, it will be downloadable. If you don't want it to be downloadable then creating a table in your view is enough

Answer (score 0):

Model is best.

There is one more option using `datatable` plugin, using which you can add buttons above table to export data in csv, excel, pdf, etc.

Check link: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html